# Как сделать ссылки rel canonical разными для разных страниц сайта

Tags: wordpress, url, header, link

Сайт на Wordpress. Сейчас на всех страницах сайта link rel="canonical" с одинаковым href - т.е. главная страница сайта.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"/>
```

Как исправить, чтобы для каждой определённой страницы был прописан свой url в href ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php rel_canonical(); ?>
```

Документация по функции доступна [по ссылке](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rel_canonical/)

Comment: ммм..ну если Вы имеете ввиду, что прописать <link rel="canonical" href="<?php rel_canonical(); ?>"/>, то ничего не получилось.

Comment: или просто вместо этой всей фразы - <?php rel_canonical(); ?>

Comment: в моём случае срабатывает только так: <?php if (is_home()){ ?>
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"/>
<?php }
else {
    ?><link rel="canonical" href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>"/><?php
}
?>               в этом случае я могу увидеть в исходном коде браузера rel canonical с разным href для определённой страницы. Но тут много кода. Думал как бы одной строкой сделать